# htaccess mod rewrite without suffix

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Im trying to rewrite urls to mysite from

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?country=uk
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.com/uk
```

but is printing a 500 error page,
Im using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?country=$1 [L]
```

I appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?country=$1 [L]
```

This will work. Remove the slash before index.php and the rewrite will work.

Comment: The slash before index: right. Why the change to the regex, though? I think the original ones should work too, and this does not do the same (in case there is a slash in the path)

Comment: I agree the change in the regex is not important for the workings of the program.

Comment: after changing the regex something wrong too, if i echo $_GET['country'], is printing "indexphp"

Comment: Are you sure you copied the full rule with the space between the regex and the original url?